# Callback functions firing midway through scrolling

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am using [fullpage](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin to create a parallax website using normal scroll which can be viewed [here](http://dev.toyinetiko.com/).

My problem is this, using callback functions onLeave or afterLoad fires midway of section scroll. You would also notice the navigation change at this point too.

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){ 
    var leavingSection = jQuery(this); 
    if(index == 1 && direction =='down'){  
        alert("Going to section 2!"); 
    } 
}
```

My question is this, how could make the alert fire only after section completion? The reason why i would like to achieve this is because i have animations which are currently disabled and would only work better with section being complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst i wasn't able to find a solution within fullpage itself, I was able to use a slightly different approach which solved the problem. By using offset from [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/), i was able to work out the distance between the bottom of browser viewport and the top of hidden box. Now, When the user scrolls and reach this distance the hidden box is revealed.